# cmd vs Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, data-access-layer

I am currently working on windows application in c# and currently I met one problem.
I started to creating the windows application in notepad++ because I not able to use VS. I am using cmd to compile the code. I will add that I have one *.dll file, which is used by the application.
Now I am trying to move my code to VS. I created new solution and I used add existing item to include my code files. I also added reference to the *.dal file. I also added using namespace statment in my MainForm.cs file. Now I get problem because when I am tryind go tompile the code I got error:

```
 The type or namespace name 'DataAccessLayer' could not be found
 (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am wondering where I made mistake?

Comment: Have you added a reference to your external DLL?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't reference the dll that you mentioned. In the solution explorer tab locate 'References', right click and select Add, then add your dll to the reference list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original post [here](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/?s=namespace).

In the project properties, change the Dotnet framework from 2.0,3.0 or 3.5 to 4, compile and run![image]